label encoding & one hot encoding
I have read somewhere that label encoding is only used for target variable and then for the input features we can use  one hot encoding (nominal ) and ordinal encoding( features having order). I am confused now cause many people are using label encoding for input features as well.
Another thing is that in one hot encoding through sklearn do we need to drop the first column as the column like gender having two categories male and female is highly correlated so we drop the first category of it.
i have searched alot on these two matters on youtube and google but every response is kind a different which ultimately makes me ponder what is the right approach to it .

This is a hard question to answer without knowing the type of model you're using. For example, the answer will be different if this is a regression-based model or a neural network. But generally, you need to think about the information you're providing the model.
Let's start with your example.  Let's assume, perhaps not correctly, that all your observations are either Male or Female. Is providing two 0/1  variables (one for each sex) giving any more information than one "Is female" variable that is 0/1?
The answer is no, you can figure out if the person is male or female with just one variable. In fact, many models will not execute with these two variables because they're perfectly collinear. A standard regression model, for example, would have to remove one of these variables to get an estimation.
Generally speaking, there is nothing wrong with label encoding. But once again, you'll need to think about how it works in your model. If this is a regression model, these two forms of data would have very different interpretations. A single value with $0,1,2,...$ has a very different interpretation to several one-hot variables. If the variables are not ordered with consistently sized differences, it is much safer to opt for one-hot variables for each category. Otherwise some models may estimate the "unit" effect of your variable. That is, 1 has effect $x$, 2 has effect $2x$ etc.

ok so you are trying to say we should remove those columns that we can figure out the value for ,like a question do you like mangoes ,it will only have yes or no as an answer which makes them perfectly collinear.then in the classfication kind of problems like fraud detection ,spam detection ,we can remove one column then cause we can figure out the other value .(if using one hot encoding)

Yes, absolutely.
